# How to Type in Telugu in LaTeX

Tags: xetex, indic

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Pothana2000}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{telugu}

\begin{document}

చేయి అనగా మానవులు, చింపాంజీలు, కోతులు మరియు లెమూర్లకు గల శరీరభాగమునకు వేళ్లు
కలబాహ్యంగము. కోలా చేతికి ఎదురెదురుగా వున్న రెండు బొటనవ్రేళ్లు వుంటాయి కాబట్టి దాని శరీరభాగాన్ని
కూడా చేయి లేక 'పా'లు అంటారు.

\end{document}
```

The above is my TeX file. It shows the following error:

> Package l3names Error: This package is obsolete --- use 'expl3'
>   instead. use 'expl3' instead}\@ehc

Comment: Update your current TeX system. I have no problem with xelatex and lualatex

Comment: @Herbert Ok for `xelatex`... With `lualatex`, the `polyglossia` package emits the following warning:  _Telugu is not supported with LuaTeX._.

Comment: @Herbert If you can get the Telugu script to render properly with lualatex from TeX Live, I'd be extremely curious to hear how.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I have no idea if it "render correctly". I can only say, that I do not get an error.

Comment: @Herbert Unfortunately, LuaTeX will happily mis-render Indic scripts (and much of Unicode), because they insist on implementing everything inside Lua instead of using standard external libraries (and this implementation has not been written). See the Wikipedia article on (so-called) [complex text layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_text_layout) ([current version](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Complex_text_layout&oldid=817269531)) for what I'm talking about.

Comment: As Herbert and Paul say, I get no errors with the above, with `xelatex` on TeX Live 2017. So you need to add more details about what's wrong. What version of XeTeX are you using, and where do you get the above errors from?

Comment: I'm voting to close because as the answer shows, there is no problem with an up-to-date distribution, and the OP has not replied to clarify.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Unfortunately, the answer shows several errors on the final line.  It does not say which TeX engine it used, so XeLaTeX might work.

Comment: @Davislor Yes, `xelatex` is what is intended (see comments above). And there are no errors if the code snippet in the question is run with `xelatex`.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Then perhaps the answer should be edited to reflect that.

Comment: @Davislor Feel free to edit (whoever posted the answer seems to have left the site...). The question mentions `\usepackage{fontspec}` so either XeTeX or LuaTeX is implicit. Anyway the answer is not relevant as all it's saying is that there's no error so the question is unanswerable unless the OP clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

Running with an up-to-date TeXLive 2017 I get:

[image]

Put `\listfiles` as first line into your document and compare the output (at the end of the log file)

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
fontspec.sty    2017/11/09 v2.6g Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
  xparse.sty    2017/12/16 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2017/12/16 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2017/12/16 L3 programming layer 
l3xdvipdfmx.def    
fontspec-xetex.sty    2017/11/09 v2.6g Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
   tuenc.def    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
fontspec.cfg
polyglossia.sty    2015/03/25 v1.42.4 Alternative to Babel for XeLaTeX and LuaL
aTeX
etoolbox.sty    2017/11/22 v2.5 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
makecmds.sty    2009/09/03 v1.0a extra command making commands
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
gloss-telugu.ldf    polyglossia: module for telugu
 ***********
```